# Opencart 2: Which method does admin --> index.php?route=api/order/add&token=xxx point to?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Where does:

admin --> `index.php?route=api/order/add&token=xxx` point to?

Which controller file, method will this call?

Answer (score 3):

index.php?route=api/order/add&token=xxx points to   catalog\controller\api

Comment: You're right, testing this on OpenCart 2.2.x, it really does route to there. That's very weeeeird! Thank you, @yeh, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: on OpenCart 3 it route the same

Answer (score -1):

It will point to

1. Controller Folder (admin/api)
2. Controller File (admin/api/order.php)
3. Controller Function (admin/api/order.php => function token())

Comment: That folder and file doesn't exist. I'm using Opencart 2.3.0.2, [check this picture](https://s27.postimg.org/9eb989t3n/hey.png) of my ftp folder structure, and you'll see that the `api/` doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

It will point to method or function Add() in the order.php controller file in the api folder.

There is no token() method as stated above. Token is just a token send with every request!

Comment: See my answer to @AliZia